# Smart House Thermostat

Tags: ruby

Noob to the Ruby, and working on my own version of the smart thermostat exercise.  I want to set a target temperature argument that is initialized and then use the current temperature argument in the method update_temperature! For some reason it's throwing an error about an undefined local variable.

Any ideas?

```
class House
  def initialize(target_temp, max_temp, min_temp)
   @target_temp   = target_temp
   @max_temp      = max_temp
   @min_temp      = min_temp
  end

  def update_temperature!(current_temp)
    @current_temp = current_temp
    if @min_temp < @current_temp && @current_temp < @target_temp
      degrees_ac_off = @target_temp - @current_temp
       puts "The current temperature is #{degrees_ac_off} below the target temperature of #{target_temp}. The air conditioner is off."
    elsif @current_temp < @min_temp
      degrees_below = @min_temp - @current_temp
      puts "The current temperature is #{degrees_below} the minimum desired temperature of #{min_temp}.  The heater is on."
    elsif @target_temp < @current_temp && @current_temp < @max_temp 
      degrees_ac = @current_temp - @target_temp
      puts "The current temperature is #{degrees_high} more than the target temperature of #{target_temp}. The air conditioner is on low."
    else  @max_temp < @current_temp 
     degrees_ac = @current_temp - @target_temp
     puts "The current temperature is #{degrees_ac} more than the target temperature of #{target_temp}. The air conditioner is on high."
     end
   end
end


my_house = House.new(71,75,60)
my_house.update_temperature!(80)
```

Comment: What's the exact error and where does it occur?

Comment: `else  @max_temp < @current_temp` is not a whole lot of use.

Comment: This code (with the NameErrors removed) switches the airco on high when the target temperature is reached.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `#{target_temp}` which calls a method, you can either put the @ symbol before it or add accessor methods for them. I prefer the latter.

```
class House
  attr_accessor :target_temp, :min_temp, :max_temp
```

Answer (score -1):

You missed `@` sign `#{target_temp}`,`#{min_temp}` as below.

- `puts "The current temperature is #{degrees_ac_off} below the target temperature of #{target_temp}. The air conditioner is off."`
- `puts "The current temperature is #{degrees_below} the minimum desired temperature of #{min_temp}.  The heater is on."`
- `puts "The current temperature is #{degrees_high} more than the target temperature of #{target_temp}. The air conditioner is on low."`
- `puts "The current temperature is #{degrees_ac} more than the target temperature of #{target_temp}. The air conditioner is on high."`

Use the below code:

```
class House
  def initialize(target_temp, max_temp, min_temp)
   @target_temp   = target_temp
   @max_temp      = max_temp
   @min_temp      = min_temp
  end

  def update_temperature!(current_temp)
    @current_temp = current_temp
    if @min_temp < @current_temp && @current_temp < @target_temp
      degrees_ac_off = @target_temp - @current_temp
       puts "The current temperature is #{degrees_ac_off} below the target temperature of #{@target_temp}. The air conditioner is off."
    elsif @current_temp < @min_temp
      degrees_below = @min_temp - @current_temp
      puts "The current temperature is #{degrees_below} the minimum desired temperature of #{@min_temp}.  The heater is on."
    elsif @target_temp < @current_temp && @current_temp < @max_temp 
      degrees_high = @current_temp - @target_temp
      puts "The current temperature is #{degrees_high} more than the target temperature of #{@target_temp}. The air conditioner is on low."
    else  @max_temp < @current_temp 
     degrees_ac = @current_temp - @target_temp
     puts "The current temperature is #{degrees_ac} more than the target temperature of #{@target_temp}. The air conditioner is on high."
     end
   end
end


my_house = House.new(71,75,60)
my_house.update_temperature!(80)
#=> The current temperature is 9 more than the target temperature of 71. The air conditioner is on high.
```

Comment: `degrees_high` is another NameError waiting to happen.

Comment: @steenslag corrected! I didn't look that,as op's code was throwing error for the above mentioned lines in my post. But thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Please refrain from asking people to vote/accept your answers. [See this meta post for more information](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167155/152134). Thanks!